# Function for writing an automated report in R

Tags: r, function

So I am trying to write an automated report in R with Functions. One of the questions I am trying to answer is this " During the first week of the month, what were the 10 most viewed products?  Show the results in a table with the product's identifier, category, and count of the number of views.". To to this I wrote the following function

```
    most_viewed_products_per_week <- function (month,first_seven_days, views){
      month <- views....February.2020.2
    
      first_seven_days <- function( month, date_1, date_2){
        date_1 <-2020-02-01
        date_2 <- 2020-02-07
          return (first_seven_days)}
    
      views <-function(views, desc){
        return (views.head(10))}
        }
    print(most_viewed_products_per_week)
```

However the output I get is this:

```
function (month,first_seven_days, views){
  month <- views....February.2020.2

  first_seven_days <- function( month, date_1, date_2){
    date_1 <-2020-02-01
    date_2 <- 2020-02-07
      return (first_seven_days)}

  views <-function(views, desc){
    return (views.head(10))}
```

How do I fix that?
This report has more questions like this, so I am trying to get my function writing as correct as possible from the start.

Thanks in advance,
Edo

Comment: Please, can you provide a sample of your data so we can reproduce it on our machines? You can use `dput(head(your_data))` an copy the output. Thanks.

Comment: Your function makes no sense. Why are `date_1` and  `date_2` arguments to `first_seven_days` if they are redefined as constants within the function ? (as in `date_1 <-2020-02-01`). Additional issues:
 The `month` argument is never used; the `views` function is a function of itself (`views(views.....))`; views.head() does not exist - looks like a poorly implemented python-like code

Comment: I also suggest you go through the tour and basic stack overflow instructions. Yoou could start with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to code in functions. Still I recommend you get your code doing what you want and then think about what parts you want to wrap in a function (for future re-use). This is to get you going.

In general: to support your analysis, make sure that your data is in the right class. I.e. dates are formatted as dates, numbers as double or integers, etc. This will give you access to many helper functions and packages.

For the case at hand, read up on `{tidyverse}`, in particular `{dplyr}` which can help you with coding `pipes`.

**simulate data**

As mentioned - you will find many friends on Stackoverflow, if you provide a reproducible example.
Your questions suggests your data look a bit like the following simulated data.
Adapt as appropriate (or provide example)

```
library(tibble)    # tibble are modern data frames
library(dplyr)     # for crunching tibbles/data frames
library(lubridate) # tidyverse package for date (and time) handling

df <- tribble(     # create row-tibble
    ~date, ~identifier, ~category, ~views
    ,"2020-02-01", 1, "TV", 27
    ,"2020-02-02", 2, "PC", 40
    ,"2020-02-03", 1, "TV", 12
    ,"2020-02-03", 2, "PC", 2
    ,"2020-02-08", 3, "UV", 200
  ) %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date))    # date is read in a character - lubridate::ymd() for date
```

This yields

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  date       identifier category views
  <date>          <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1 2020-02-01          1 TV          27
2 2020-02-02          2 PC          40
3 2020-02-03          1 TV          12
4 2020-02-03          2 PC           2
5 2020-02-08          3 UV         200
```

Notice: date-column is in date-format.

**work your algorithm**

From your attempt it follows you want to extract the first 7 days.
Since we have a "date"-column, we can use a date-function to help us here.
`{lubridate}`'s `day()` extracts the "day-number".

```
> df %>% filter(day(date) <= 7) 
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  date       identifier category views
  <date>          <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1 2020-02-01          1 TV          27
2 2020-02-02          2 PC          40
3 2020-02-03          1 TV          12
4 2020-02-03          2 PC           2
```

Anything outside the first 7 days is gone.

Next you want to `summarise` to get your product views total.

```
df %>% 
## ---------- c.f. above ------------
  filter(day(date) <= 7) %>% 
## ---------- summarise in bins that you need := groups -------
  group_by(identifier, category) %>% 
  summarise(total_views = sum(views)
            , .groups = "drop" )      # if grouping is not needed "drop" it
```

This gives you:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  identifier category total_views
       <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1          1 TV                39
2          2 PC                42
```

Now pick the `top-10` and sort the order:

```
df %>% 
## ---------- c.f. above ------------
  filter(day(date) <= 7) %>% 
  group_by(identifier, category) %>% 
  summarise(total_views = sum(views), .groups = "drop" ) %>% 
## ---------- make use of another helper function of dplyr
  top_n(n = 10, total_views) %>%    # note top-10 makes here no "real" sense :), try top_n(1, total_views) 
  arrange(desc(total_views))      # arrange in descending order on total_views
```

**wrap in function**

Now that the workflow is in place, think about breaking your code into the blocks you think are useful.

I leave this to you. You can assign interim results to new data frames and wrap the preparation of the data into a function and then the `top_n() %>% arrange()` in another function, ...

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  identifier category total_views
       <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1          2 PC                42
2          1 TV                39
```